# Ability to make interactive contrls on canvas

Tags: canvas, dart, rikulo

i am wanting to attempt to write a 2d CAD package with Rikulo.

THis requires interacting with the shapes and having a sense of Paper space scale.

DO you think this is possible ?

Maybe you can point me to some examples ?

Answer (score 0):

To Rikulo, the canvas is just [a view](http://api.rikulo.org/ui/latest/rikulo_view/Canvas.html) you can draw something on it. To implement a 2D CAD application, I think you need also a canvas framework, such as [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/). Not sure if there is a Dart counterpart. You might consider to port it:)